# Passing arrays to shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm declaring a hash map in bash, then trying to return the value of a lookup within a new shell.

So the map is defined as follows:

```
declare -x -A hashmap
hashmap=( ["index1"]="thisisone" ["index2"]="thisistwo")
```

Now I want to issue a parallel instances of a command where I find the paths for the files I want to process, lookup a value in the table according to which file is being processed, then store the lookup value in the shelled command for later use:

```
find . -name '*.bam' | xargs -n 1 -P $threads -iFILES bash -c 'var=$(echo '${hashmap[FILES]}')'
```

There seem to be a few issues here, first off the FILES variable isn't being passed properly to the lookup. I've tried assigning FILES to a local variable, and passing the local variable as a literal, however I get "bad array subscript" error.

```
find . -name '*.bam' | xargs -n 1 -P $threads -iFILES bash -c 'var=$(echo FILES); echo '${hashmap["$(echo $var)"]}';'
```

I have tried dumping the entire map:

```
find . -name '*.bam' | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -iFILES bash -c 'v="@"; echo '${hashmap["$v"]}''
```

Which gives the same subscript error, however when I just pass the @ character directly it works:

```
find . -name '*.bam' | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -iFILES bash -c 'echo '${hashmap[@]}''
```

Any ideas how I can get the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Marty

Comment: (At least) two problems here: `sh` doesn't handle (associative) arrays; and (in Bash), arrays can't be exported. Your design is hopeless.

Comment: isn't declare -x an export?

Comment: also like i said the last command instance works when i "find . -name '*.bam' | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -iFILES sh -c 'echo '${hashmap[@]}''" so isn't hasmap being exported? how else would the shell find it?

Comment: It is, but arrays can't be exported. See `man bash`: _Array variables may not (yet) be exported._

Comment: In the last command, the expansion `${hashmap[@]}` is expanded by the subshell (before the `sh` is even launched: count the number of single quotes); it is expanded _not because it is exported_, but _because it is expanded by the current shell._

Comment: In the second to last example, `${hashmap["$v"]}` is expanded _before_ the `bash` is launched: hence the expansion `$v` that appears here is expanded before the `v="@"` assignment… Your design is hopeless.

Comment: ok, im just trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: why can't i work around this by doing: for f in $(find . -name '*sort.bam'); do echo ${chipassoc[$f]}; done

Comment: when the following works: for f in $(find . -name '*sort.bam'); do echo ${chipassoc[@]}; done

Comment: let me guess, it has to do with the expansion of ${}

Comment: nevermind, i figures it out, i wasnt assigning to the array appropriately. thanks for the clarifications.